# How can I stop anacron.timer?

Tags: lubuntu, anacron

I stopped temporarily crons with

```
  sudo service cron stop
  sudo service anacron stop
```

I got message

```
Warning: Stopping anacron.service, but it can still be activated by:
  anacron.timer
```

`sudo service anacron.timer stop` failed with `anacron.timer: unrecognized service`

How can I stop also this one?

I am running Lubuntu 20.04

I found `/lib/systemd/system/anacron.timer` with

```
[Unit]
Description=Trigger anacron every hour

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 07..23:30
RandomizedDelaySec=5m
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Comment: pretty sure you stop them in the same way as services, `systemctl stop anacron.timer` and `systemctl mask anacron.timer` if you want to disable it permanently.

Comment: @bac0n `sudo systemctl stop anacron.timer` `sudo systemctl start anacron.timer` is not triggering any errors. Are you interested in posting this as an answer?